# Order of elements of $G/H$ where $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=<(0,2)>$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was asked to find the order of the elements in $G/H$ where $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=<(0,2)>$.

I found $G/H$ to be $\{H,(0,1)+H,(1,0)+H,(1,1)+H\}$ which I think is right.

Then I proceeded to find the order of the elements in $G/H$.

$H$ is of order $1$.

$(0,1)+H$ is of order $4$ because $[(0,1)+H]+[(0,1)+H]+[(0,1)+H]+[(0,1)+H]=(0,4)+H=H=e$

$(1,0)+H$ is of order $2$ because $[(1,0)+H]+[(1,0)+H]=(2,0)+H=H=e$

$(1,1)+H$ is of order $4$ because $[(1,1)+H]+[(1,1)+H]+[(1,1)+H]+[(1,1)+H]=(4,4)+H=H=e$

According to the solutions though $(0,1)+H$ and $(1,1)+H$ are of order $2$. Can someone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: For $(0,1) + H$, note that $(0,2) + H = (0,0) + H$, since $H = \{(0,0), (0,2)\}$.

Comment: So when finding the order in this scenario, you just keep adding on $(a,b)$ until you get something that's in $H$?

Comment: Order of H is 2. Order of G is 8.

Comment: @user326441 Yes. Because if $g \in H$, then $g+H = H$. That's what quotient groups do: They lump together things that aren't really equal into (co)sets that are equal. And if your $H$ is normal, then this works out in a nice and consistent manner.

Comment: Okay got it thanks so much @Arthur!

Comment: @jnyan The order of $H$ as an element in $G/H$ is $1$, though.

Comment: If you mean H as an element in quotient group then yes. Since it is identity